# Build a simple proxy

Tags: code-golf, internet, networking

Make the shortest proxy server.

#### Input/Output Specifications

Client:

- Input: a port number (32-bit integer) **(,) or (space)** a url (see test cases)
- Output: html source of the url

Server:

- Input: port to listen to (32-bit integer)
- Output: **REC** when input is received from the client, **OK** when finished sending the html source to the client.

#### Rules

- You may make either a **complete program** or **functions in an interpreted language**.
- Input is taken through **stdin** or given as a **arguments**.
- Your code has to work for the given **test cases only** (more is optional, less is invalid).
- The client output has to be the same as with what you get when you "view source" from a browser.
- The server **may exit** after each handled request (i.e does not have to be persistent/daemon)
- (**edit**) Any other input/output than what specified, is forbidden.

#### Test cases (client inputs)

1. N<sub>1</sub> https://stackoverflow.com/
2. N<sub>2</sub> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server
3. N<sub>3</sub> http://stackexchange.com/search?q=code+golf

where N<sub>i</sub> are random integers between 1 and 2048.

Comment: Does the server have to be reusable?  Or can it be a one-shot proxy?

Comment: @Nemo: what do you mean reusable? (but I suppose the answer is "yes it can be a one-shot")

Comment: @Nemo: yes, it is ok if the server exits after a well handled request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ZSH - 57 + 42 characters

Server:

```
s=$(nc -l $1)
echo REC
curl -s $s|nc 127.0.0.1 $1
echo OK
```

Client:

```
echo $2|nc 127.0.0.1 $1
echo "$(nc -l $1)"
```

Usage:

```
sudo zsh server.zsh 123

sudo zsh client.zsh 123 http://stackoverflow.com/
sudo zsh client.zsh 123 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server
sudo zsh client.zsh 123 "http://stackexchange.com/search?q=code+golf"
```

Comment: It's been a while since I last used zsh, but can't you get rid of all the quotes (necessary for bash) when using that shell?

Comment: @idealmachine: The ones on the second line of the client I think are necessary, I was only getting the footer back from the StackExchange search. The other ones, I'm not sure about, seems to work without them though.  I don't really do much scripting in zsh.

Comment: Yes, curl should be silenced (updated rules to clarify).